# android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ,unable to start activity

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I'm trying to make a live wallpaper service, the wallpaper service runs fine but I'm getting this

```
03-20 19:13:21.039: E/AndroidRuntime(4147): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-20 19:13:21.039: E/AndroidRuntime(4147): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
03-20 19:13:21.039: E/AndroidRuntime(4147):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2144)
03-20 19:13:21.039: E/AndroidRuntime(4147):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
03-20 19:13:21.039: E/AndroidRuntime(4147):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
03-20 19:13:21.039: E/AndroidRuntime(4147):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
03-20 19:13:21.039: E/AndroidRuntime(4147):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-20 19:13:21.039: E/AndroidRuntime(4147):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
03-20 19:13:21.039: E/AndroidRuntime(4147):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
03-20 19:13:21.039: E/AndroidRuntime(4147):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-20 19:13:21.039: E/AndroidRuntime(4147):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
03-20 19:13:21.039: E/AndroidRuntime(4147):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
03-20 19:13:21.039: E/AndroidRuntime(4147):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
03-20 19:13:21.039: E/AndroidRuntime(4147):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-20 19:13:21.039: E/AndroidRuntime(4147): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
03-20 19:13:21.039: E/AndroidRuntime(4147):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-20 19:13:21.039: E/AndroidRuntime(4147):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
03-20 19:13:21.039: E/AndroidRuntime(4147):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2139)
03-20 19:13:21.039: E/AndroidRuntime(4147):     ... 11 more
03-20 19:13:21.039: E/AndroidRuntime(4147): Caused by: 
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: 
Unable to find explicit activity class {com.miccialabs.liveballwallpaper/com.miccialabs.LiveBallWallpaperSettings};
have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
03-20 19:13:21.039: E/AndroidRuntime(4147):     at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1405)
03-20 19:13:21.039: E/AndroidRuntime(4147):     at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1379)
03-20 19:13:21.039: E/AndroidRuntime(4147):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:2827)
03-20 19:13:21.039: E/AndroidRuntime(4147):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:2933)
03-20 19:13:21.039: E/AndroidRuntime(4147):     at com.android.wallpaper.livepicker.LiveWallpaperPreview.configureLiveWallpaper(LiveWallpaperPreview.java:125)
03-20 19:13:21.039: E/AndroidRuntime(4147):     ... 14 more
03-20 19:13:21.046: E/(1516): Dumpstate > /data/log/dumpstate_app_error
```

when I try to access it's settings,
here's the manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.miccialabs.liveballwallpaper"
android:versionName="1"
android:versionCode="1">

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.software.live_wallpaper" />

<application android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:permission="android.permission.BIND_WALLPAPER">

<activity 
        android:name="com.miccialabs.liveballwallpaper.LiveBallWallpaperSettings"
        android:label="@string/liveWallpaper_settings"
        android:exported="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher">
    </activity>


    <service android:name="com.miccialabs.liveballwallpaper.BallLiveWallpaper"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.service.wallpaper.WallpaperService" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data android:name="android.service.wallpaper"
            android:resource="@xml/livewallpaper" />

    </service>
</application>
```

and here's the settings activity:

```
package com.miccialabs.liveballwallpaper;

import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceActivity;

public class LiveBallWallpaperSettings extends PreferenceActivity
implements SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener
{
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle icicle)
{
    super.onCreate(icicle);
  getPreferenceManager().setSharedPreferencesName(com.miccialabs.liveballwallpaper.BallLiveWallpaper.SHARED_PREFS_NAME);
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.livewallpaper_settings);
    getPreferenceManager().getSharedPreferences()
            .registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
}

@Override
protected void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy()
{
    getPreferenceManager().getSharedPreferences()
            .unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
    super.onDestroy();
}

public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences,
        String key)
{
}
}
```

what am I missing ? it says unable to find explicit activity class but I've declared it, so what's wrong?

Comment: how do you start it ? Why is it looking for com.miccialabs.LiveBallWallpaperSettings?

Comment: `com.miccialabs.LiveBallWallpaperSettings` I cannot see this in your manifest.  I can see `com.miccialabs.liveballwallpaper.BallLiveWallpaper`, or `com.miccialabs.liveballwallpaper.LiveBallWallpaperSettings` but whichever, you have **not** declared the class.

Comment: Look at the line 125 on your LiveWallpaperPreciew class for an Class which isnt existing

Comment: the activity is declared on line 15 od the manifest, and the LiveWallpaperPreview is an api class

Comment: Can you show the code where you are starting the intent? My guess is that you have mentioned the wrong package name in there.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, android tries to locate your Activity here:

```
com.miccialabs.liveballwallpaper/com.miccialabs.LiveBallWallpaperSettings
```

So probably the "package" in your LiveBallWallpaperSettings.java is not correctly defined.

Also you already declared your package ("com.miccialabs.liveballwallpaper"), so for the Activity's name you should use only .ActivityName like this:

```
<activity 
    android:name=".LiveBallWallpaperSettings"
    android:label="@string/liveWallpaper_settings"
    android:exported="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher">
</activity>
```

Hope it helps.